# Ansible: execute command output, into another command

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, redhat

I'm planning to create and run an ansible playbook (or a .sh script) that will detect the last user login, then if the login date is older than 30 days proceed to shutdown the server, otherwise stop the playbook.

My knowledge in ansible is basic and scripting too. :(

I'll execute this on my RHEL servers 6.x and 7.x

## Execute last command for the test user

```
last | grep test
test     pts/1        127.0.0.1     Mon Sep 9 10:53 - 10:53  (00:00)
```

Save this output, if the date is older than 30 days, shutdown the server. How could i set this output as a variable into the next command ?

```sh
if [ "$(date +%D)" != "30" ];then

    shutdown -h now
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is how i solved the problem

```
---
- name: Check last login
  hosts: REDHAT
  tasks: 
    - name: Last logged user
      shell: last | grep myusername
      register: output
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: shutdown server
      shell: shutdown -h now
      become: yes
      when: (output.stdout|int - ansible_date_time.epoch|int) < 2592000
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to come up with this yourself but here is what you can start with:

```
- name: Check user logged in (30 days)
  shell: last | grep test
  register: user_last_login
  ignore_errors: True

- name: Shut down server if no user login
  shell: shutdown -h now
  become: yes
  when: user_last_login
```

I won't give you the last bit (how to check if user_last_login is older than 30 days).

Hint (there are functions in Ansible to deal with time (based on Python):

```
( '10 Apr 19 12:52 UTC'|to_datetime("%d %b %y %H:%M %Z") - "1970 UTC"|to_datetime("%Y %Z")).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. I'm still kinda lost using this filter to_datetime